# Jquery Shuffle plugin not working - no errors present

Tags: javascript, jquery, shuffle

I have a series of `ul`s whose order I want to shuffle (not the order of the `li`s within, just the `ul`s).

I have tried to implement the Shuffle plugin demonstrated [here](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/shuffling-the-dom/), however it does not work.

My HTML is:

```
<div id="swap">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

And function is:

```
    $.fn.shuffle = function() {

        var allElems = this.get(),
            getRandom = function(max) {
                return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
            },
            shuffled = $.map(allElems, function(){
                var random = getRandom(allElems.length),
                    randEl = $(allElems[random]).clone(true)[0];
                allElems.splice(random, 1);
                return randEl;
           });

        this.each(function(i){
            $(this).replaceWith($(shuffled[i]));
        });

        return $(shuffled);

    };

 $('#swap ul').shuffle();
```

But I just cannot get it working.

There are no errors in the Console either.

Would anyone know what I am doing wrong?